# How to create a duplicate list in python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to create a date list that- contains the list of dates of one week but each date should be there 4 times in that list. like this:

```
[1-jan-2018, 1-jan-2018, 1-jan-2018, 1-jan-2018, 2-jan-2018, 2-jan-2018, 2-jan-2018, 2-jan-2018, 3-jan-2018, 3-jan-2018, 3-jan-2018, 3-jan-2018, 4-jan-2018, 4-jan-2018, 4-jan-2018, 4-jan-2018, 5-jan-2018, 5-jan-2018, 5-jan-2018, 5-jan-2018, 6-jan-2018, 6-jan-2018, 6-jan-2018, 6-jan-2018,7-jan-2018, 7-jan-2018, 7-jan-2018, 7-jan-2018]
```

I don't exactly have the idea how to do it but here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
timeSeries = list(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='7/1/2020')) 
print(timeSeries)
```

This will just create the list of dates of one week but I want the answer in the above format. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to duplicate items in a list

A solution is create various list with each element of your primary list repeated N time. In this example, I will duplicated each element four times, so:

```
old_list = [1,2,3,4]
# [i,i,i,i] will clone each item four times.
new_list = list([i,i,i,i] for i in old_list)
# new_list = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

But, now you will have a list of lists, so you need to transform that result into a list of elements, this operation is called **flat**. In order to do this in python, you can use the [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
import itertools
old_list = [1,2,3,4]
# [i,i,i,i] will clone each item four times.
new_list = list([i,i,i,i] for i in old_list)
# new_list = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
new_list_flatten = list(itertools.chain(*new_list))
# new_list_flatten = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

You can avoid the usage of `*` operation by calling  [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
import itertools
old_list = [1,2,3,4]
# [i,i,i,i] will clone each item four times.
new_list = list([i,i,i,i] for i in old_list)
# new_list = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
new_list_flatten = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(new_list))
# new_list_flatten = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Therefore, this is a code that do what you want:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
time_series = list(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='7/1/2020')) 
newseries = list( itertools.chain.from_iterable((i,i,i,i) for i in time_series) )
print(newseries)
```